# Does recent version Mockito support JDK 17 (openJDK 17)?

Tags: mockito, java-17

I didn't see any release notes of Mockito mentioned it supports JDK 17 or OpenJDK 17 and plus?

I am planning to migrate from JMockit to Mockito since it doesn't support JDK 17. But before I change any existing code, I'd like to make sure it supports.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Convert one test (or add a new one) and add mockito and see what happens when you run the test?

Comment: Yse, it even supports 21. See release notes: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases. In particular: [Mockito 5: prepare for future JDK versions](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v5.0.0)